# Looping incremental dates in Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to create a loop which opens a new Chrome tab every time with incremental date links -
for eg: www.biguser.com/31-04-2015, then open www.biguser.com/01-05-2015
After opening the link, it clicks on a downloadable link (using Selenium) which has a standard .csv format. So I search for a link with `find_element _by_partial_link_text` for 'csv' and then click on the link.

Here's the code -

```
from datetime import timedelta, date
import selenium.webdriver as webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
import time
import urllib2
import re
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

link_1 = "https://www.biguser.com/date=" #this is part 1 (prefix) of the link
link_2 = "&section=q" #this part comes after date is put in dd-mm-yyyy format

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
#loop for determining the increments in date
def daterange(start_date, end_date):
    for n in range(int ((end_date - start_date).days)):
        yield start_date + timedelta(n)

start_date = date(2013, 12, 31) #defining my start date
end_date = date(2015, 12, 31) #defining my end date

while True:
#loop begins
        for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
            driver.get(link_1+single_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")+link_2) #opens the concatenated link
            driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('csv').click() #finds 'csv' text and clicks on the link that contains it
            time.sleep(5) #waits for 5 seconds for everything to settle down
            driver.get("chrome://newtab/") #opens a new Chrome tab
```

and here's the problem I have with it
The downloadable files are only available for WEEKDAYS, that means that there is no 'csv' on the page instead just an error message that says "            No file found for specified date. Try another date." Whenever the code encounters this, it simply quits the program.

I would like the code to simply skip the "click the link" event in case the link is not available and proceed with the next date. The page doesn't have a href or tag.

PS: As an extreme beginner, I have put together this code through various experiments (as you can see I have loaded too many libraries too ;))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date class has a weekday() method you can use to check if a given date is a weekday. I would recommend making a little helper function for an if statement:

```
def is_weekday(date_object):
    # days 1-5 are weekdays, 6 and 7 are weekends
    return date.weekday(date_object) in range(1,6)
```

Then you could check:

```
if is_weekday(<your date here>):
  ...make the link...
```

If there are other factors like holidays, you will probably not be able to anticipate all of these, so I would recommend a try/except block surrounding the action(s) that fails:

```
for single_date in daterange(start_date, end_date):
  try:
    driver.get(link_1+single_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")+link_2) #opens the concatenated link
    driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('csv').click() #finds 'csv' text and clicks on the link that contains it
    time.sleep(5) #waits for 5 seconds for everything to settle down
    driver.get("chrome://newtab/") #opens a new Chrome tab
  except:
    continue  #this will return to the top of the loop and move on to the next link
```

Comment: I could try that, but that wouldn't solve the problem since there are other holidays within the week. I need the loop to go to the next link in case it cannot find the clickable link. This is my logic as I understand it.